# Trying to run subprocess commands with carriage returns and newlinees

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to perform some commands to remove useless output from a file, I've figured out the necessary commands to do this although when trying to automate it through python, find the command is cut off midway through because part of the text I am trying to remove, is a carriage return.

```
def do_stuff():
    count = 0
    while True:
            try:
                count += 1
                basic_filename = fn + str(count) + ".txt"
                temp_filename = "temp_"+fn + str(count) + ".txt"
                final_filename = "final_"+fn + str(count) + ".txt"
                finalfinal_filename = "finalfinal_"+fn + str(count) + ".txt"

                cmd1 = b"sed -e 's/\\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mK]//g' -e 's/\r//g' -e 's/\\n//g' " + str.encode(basic_filename) + b" > " + str.encode(temp_filename)
                cmd1 = base64.b64encode(cmd1)
                cmd1 = "echo '"+bytes.decode(cmd1)+"' | base64 -d | bash"
                print(cmd1)
            except:
                break
```

An example output includes the Base64

```
"c2VkIC1lICdzL1x4MWJcW1swLTk7XSpbbUtdLy9nJyAtZSAncy8NLy9nJyAtZSAncy9cbi8vZycgcmVzdWx0czEudHh0ID4gdGVtcF9yZXN1bHRzMS50eHQ=" which when decoded shows: 

"sed -e 's/\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mK]//g' -e 's/

//g' -e 's/\n//g' results1.txt > temp_results1.txt"
```

Comment: use `rb` instead of `b` for raw input else backslashes will be interpreted.

Comment: but this is still not very good. You'd be better off without `sed` and native `re` module which can do the same and more. `sed` is not present on all systems, has different versions and is slow if you loop on it (which means running several processes), it makes your python code less python...

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding -- and then decoding -- your string? Also, it doesn't look like you ever *execute* your command line, so you may be chasing a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @larsks You can't execute OS commands that are bytes, so converting it to  Base64 and decoding in the terminal is a workaround for this, and the code is purely for checking the payload rather then executing it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't execute OS commands that are bytes

Of course you can. Instead of writing a shell script, you can run your commands like this:

```py
import subprocess

basic_filename = "example.txt"
with open(basic_filename, "wb") as fd:
    fd.write(b"there is no \x1b[12;m escape")

out = subprocess.check_output(
    [
        b"sed",
        b"-e",
        b"s/\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[mk]//g",
        basic_filename.encode(),
    ]
)

print(out)
```

That will print out:

```
b'there is no  escape'
```

...having successfully removed the escape sequence. Of course, as others have pointed out in the comments, there's no reason to be calling out to `sed` to perform these transformations; just do it in Python instead:

```
import re

re_esc = re.compile(b"\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[mk]")

input_data = b"there is no \x1b[12;m escape"
out = re_esc.sub(b"", input_data)
print(out)
```